# How to configure Format Document in VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

When I hit the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, my editor reformat my C/C++ code, the same as in Eclipse or Vim. However I have absolutely no clues on how to configure it.

What are the rules used to reformat the document. I know the action is `editor.action.formatDocument`, but I found nothing in the user settings.

How does it work? How to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `clang` and `clang-format`.
Then add a `.clang-format` file in your project directory containing (as an example) :

```
BinPackArguments: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup
ColumnLimit: 0
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
IndentWidth: 4
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
UseTab: Never
```

All clang-format style options can be found here :
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html